# Can't export vertex colors in edit mode

Tags: python, export, vertex-colors

I'm trying to write an export script to output vertices and vertex colors in a simple format. The script I've created appears to work fine when run during "Object" or "Vertex Paint" mode, but when I try running it during "Edit Mode" it crashes and doesn't work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def do_export(context, filepath):
    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data
    mesh.calc_normals_split()

    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        for poly in mesh.polygons:
            for loop_index in poly.loop_indices:
                loop = mesh.loops[loop_index]
                vert = mesh.vertices[loop.vertex_index]

                f.write("v %.4f %.4f %.4f\n" % vert.co[:])
                f.write("c %i " % (mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[0] * 255))
                f.write("%i " % (mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[1] * 255))
                f.write("%i\n" % (mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[2] * 255))
                f.write("\n")
```

And the error I get:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pubby/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/export.py", line 62, in execute
    exported = do_export(context,  filepath)
  File "/home/pubby/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/export.py", line 39, in do_export
    f.write("c %i " % (mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[0] * 255))
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 0 out of range, size 0

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Set it to *Object mode* before you begin:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

...
I tried running your code.  It doesn't do anything over here in any mode.

```
import bpy
def export(filepath):
  obj = bpy.context.object
  mesh = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
  obj.data.calc_normals_split()

  with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    for poly in obj.data.polygons:
      for loop_index in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = poly.loop_indices[loop_index]
        vert = mesh.data.vertices[loop]

        f.write("v %.4f %.4f %.4f\n" % vert.co[:])
        f.write("c %i " % (mesh.data.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[0] * 255))
        f.write("%i " % (mesh.data.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[1] * 255))
        f.write("%i\n" % (mesh.data.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[2] * 255))
        f.write("\n")
```

It throws: *IndexError: range object index out of range*
I don't think *mesh.data.vertices* is pointing to the right number though.